# Windows phone Listbox not working properly when there are lots of items

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, selecteditem

I am using Listbox in windows phone 8 to show a dynamic list and i want to select the ListItem in edit mode and by selecting means i show img in the list. Which i am able to do. but when i scroll the list, items which i have selected are changed. Some other item is selected. this is a random behaviour.
Below is my code.

---

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstbxReg"
                 Margin="0 130 0 0"
                 Tap="lstbxReg_Tap"
                 VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                 >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                            BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}"
                            Margin="0 0 0 5"
                            Tag="lstRegBorder">
                        <StackPanel Width="380"  
                                  Tag="{Binding ID}"   >
                            <TextBlock Text="Date:" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       Padding="15 0 0 0"
                                       Width="150"
                                       Margin="0 0 0 -30"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <!--/Assets/1.png-->
                            <Image x:Name="LstImg"
                                   Source="{Binding ImgURL}"
                                   Tag="{Binding ID}"
                                   Width="30" Height="25"
                                   Margin="0 5 10 0"
                                   Loaded="LstImg_Loaded"
                                   VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtdate" 
                                       Text="{Binding Date}" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Margin="0 -30 30 0"
                                       Width="160"
                                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Type:" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Padding="15 0 0 0"
                                       Width="150"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtType" 
                                       Text="{Binding Category}" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Margin="0 -25 50 0"
                                       Width="140"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="SMS No:" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Padding="15 0 0 0"
                                       Width="150"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtSmsno" 
                                       Text="{Binding CustomerSMSNo}" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Margin="0 -25 50 0"
                                       Width="140"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Customer:" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Padding="15 0 0 0"
                                       Width="150"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtCust" 
                                       Text="{Binding CustomerInfo}" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Margin="0 -25 50 0"
                                       Width="140"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Duration:" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Padding="15 0 0 0"
                                       Width="150"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtDuration" 
                                       Text="{Binding Total}" 
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Margin="0 -25 50 0"
                                       Width="140"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

******Code *****

```
public void bind()
    {
        List<Class> lst = new List<Class>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(new Class
            {
                ID = i,
                BorderColor = "Green",
                URL = "/Assets/1.png",
                Date = DateTime.Today.ToString(),
                Category = "wr",
                CustomerSMSNo = "134578",
                CustomerInfo = "asd",
                Total = "12"
            });
        }

        lstbxReg.ItemsSource = lst;

    }

    private void lstbxReg_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItemList = (Class)lstbxReg.SelectedItem;

        position = lstbxReg.SelectedIndex;
        var selected = (Class)lstbxReg.SelectedItem;
        if (selected.imgURL == "/Assets/1.png")
        {
            selected.imgURL = "/Assets/checkbox_Filled_green.png";


            int index = lstImg.FindIndex(x => x.Tag.ToString() == selected.ID.ToString());

            lstImg[index].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selected.imgURL, UriKind.Relative));

        }
        else
        {
            selected.imgURL = "/Assets/1.png";


            int index = lstImg.FindIndex(x => x.Tag.ToString() == selected.ID.ToString());

            lstImg[index].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selected.imgURL, UriKind.Relative));

        }
        lstbxReg.SelectedItem = null;
        lstbxReg.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void LstImg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Img = sender as Image;
        int count = lstImg.FindAll(x => x.Tag.ToString() == Img.Tag.ToString()).Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            lstImg.Add(Img);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a random thing.

`Listbox` uses data virtualization. It creates only limited count of those items, which are visible at the same time on screen. As you scroll down it reuses the item that is scrolled up and not visible anymore.

You are using data binding which is a good thing.
But you are making changes to the `item` of `Listbox` and not the **source list** which is bound. So make changes in the **source list** and `Listbox` will update correctly as long as `Listbox` receives change *notifications*.

The source list named **lst**, you should keep a reference to it to make changes.

P.S. Work on your naming conversions. A `class` with a name **Class** and mostly all naming mixed up makes it very hard to read.